# why is my list Nonetype? in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i dont understand why my list in Nonetype. im trying to build a function that receives a list of int, which the first index is the pivot and then sorts the rest of the list so each int that is greater than the pivot will be on the right side and int that are smaller than the pivot will be on the left. the int's dont need to be sorted from smallest to biggest.
this is my code:

```
def divide_list(lst):
    pivot = lst[0]
    lst= lst.reverse()
    for i in lst:
        if i>pivot:
            lst.append(i)
            lst.remove(i)
    return lst
```

thanks!

Comment: As a general rule: if a method has important side-effects (e.g. all functions that perform an operation "in-place"), then it returns `None`. In some other languages when a method doesn't have any meaningful result they return `self`, to allow concatenation of method calls (like `lst.append(1).reverse().append(3)`), but this is not python case.

Comment: Why don't you just use the last item as the pivot, then you don't need to reverse...

Comment: @user2751595: you're supposed to accept one of the answers provided.

Answer (score 3):

`lst.reverse()` reverses the list **in place** and returns `None`. Don't assign the return value back to `lst`:

```
def divide_list(lst):
    pivot = lst[0]
    lst.reverse()
    for i in lst:
        if i>pivot:
            lst.append(i)
            lst.remove(i)
    return lst
```

If you don't want `lst` to be changed in-place, use a negative slice to get a new copy of the list in reverse order:

```
def divide_list(lst):
    pivot = lst[0]
    lst = lst[::-1]
    for i in lst:
        if i>pivot:
            lst.append(i)
            lst.remove(i)
    return lst
```

This still will result in various problems; your approach won't work as you are altering the list in-place in the `for` loop. As you add and remove elements to the list, the iterator does *not* get updated and the list behaviour will not be what you expect.

Say you have a list `[3, 4, 1, 2]` after reversal, the pivot being `2`. In the loop, the iterator used by the `for` loop looks at `lst[0]`, and you'd move `3` to the end of the list by appending and removing. Now the list looks like `[4, 1, 2, 3]` and the loop advances to `lst[1]`, so to the `1` value. `4` has been skipped altogether!

Comment: `lst.reverse` -- That's one I'm not accustomed to seeing much.  I think it's a lot more common to see `reversed`.  This code is still a little strange (e.g. iterating over the list and modifying it at the same time)

Comment: @mgilson: `reversed()` returns an iterator, so you cannot use `lst.append()` after that, hence the use of `[::-1]` instead.

Comment: Right.  I'm still not completely sure what OP's code is actually trying to accomplish, so it's a bit tricky to say what the best way to do it is.  generally, one would just use `for i in reversed(lst)`, so you could still do list stuff with `lst`.  But, you generally don't want to do that while iterating over it.

Comment: @mgilson: He reverses the list so pivot will be at the end, then he appends anything that is larger...

Comment: @thebjorn -- Makes sense, but there's the whole iterating while modifying.  so, if `i` is greater than pivot, it gets moved to the end, and then that element will be hit at the end of iterating resulting in an infinite loop (I think).

Comment: @thebjorn -- Scratch the infinite loop.  the `remove` maintains the length invariant.  However, the element after the one you removed and appended to the end of the list will get skipped in iteration, and the element removed and appended will be visited multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to modify the list you're iterating over; it'll also get slow with larger input lists. Better to use a new list instead for building the result.

```
def divide_list(lst):
    ret = []  # might replace with collections.deque
              # for better performance with larger inputs
    pivot = lst[0]
    for i in reversed(lst):
        if i > pivot:
            ret.append(i)
        else:
            ret.insert(0, i)
    return ret
```

Also, you can use 2 separate lists and then return them as a tuple, or concatenate them at the end:

```
def divide_list(lst):
    left, right = [], []
    pivot = lst[0]
    for i in reversed(lst):
        (right if i > pivot else left).append(i)
    return left + right  # or (left, right)
```

or you can even do 2 iterations over the list but avoid costly `append` or concatenation operations, by using a generator:

```
def divide_list(lst):
    pivot = lst[0]
    for i in reversed(lst):
        if i < pivot: yield i
    for i in reversed(lst):
        if i >= pivot: yield i

new_list = list(divide_list(orig_list))
```

Comment: Is append or concatenation more costly than a generator? I thought generators involved shuffling frames around...

Comment: @thebjorn: the constant overhead of a generator might be higher, but it should be O(n) because it doesn't involve exponentially costly memory operations; if you prepend to a list all the time, for example, you'll have a lot of copying going around.

Comment: Using timeit (number=10000) and a random list of 10 000 integers, I get: 235.97 secs(!) for algorithm #1, 7.96 secs for #2, and 6.92 secs for #3 (the algorithm from my answer, with a reverse call added for similarity, was 6.22 secs.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're implementing a quicksort.  If that's the case, I might do something like this:

```
def divide_list(lst):
    pivot = lst[0]
    left = []
    right = []
    for item in lst:
        if item > pivot:
            right.append(item)
        else:
            left.append(item)
    return left, right
```

Of course, if you want a single list at the end, you could do something interesting like:

```
    return left[::-1] + right
```

to reverse left and then concatenate that with right.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided you with an explanation for what is going wrong, but perhaps you'd consider a more straight-forward implementation?

```
def divide_list(lst):
    pivot = lst[0]
    return [i for i in lst if i <= pivot] + [i for i in lst if i > pivot]
```

Comment: I've also provided that solution, for the record :)

Comment: I see that now :-)   Did you consider `[left, right][i > pivot].append(i)` ... *ducking* ;-)

Comment: Not really, but then it should be `(left, right)[i > pivot]`, for semantic correctness, and it's still not as readable as the ternary if; not sure about the performance either :P

Comment: The performance of the ternary operator version is marginally faster than the boolean index.